# How to manage superior assigning task

Tags: management

An executive-level manager from a non-Support team keeps assigning one of my team members tasks directly without involving me. This work takes up a lot of my time and impacts my team’s performance goals. This executive-level manager is much "higher up" in the company than I am. I have asked him to please include me when such requests are made of one of my team members, but the executive-level manager continues to make direct requests anyway. How should I respond?

Comment: I'd suggest replacing the generic "your manager" with "my manager" as that only complicates the question. You should probably also add how many levels these people are apart, what you've already tried and what your priorities are (keeping the peace versus  getting it to stop).

Comment: @rahul, I reworded the question to be in first person so it is a little easier to understand. If you believe I have made any mistakes, feel free to [edit] the question.

Answer (score 9):

If you're the manager, then inform your staff member that they need to get approval from you to action anything from outside the team. This is normal procedure, it makes sure you're in the loop for everything and can schedule work around superiors needs.

It also means that every single time your staff member is interfered with, you're basically reiterating to the superior in question that you need to be in the loop. They're unlikely to interfere with how you run your team by overtly telling your subordinate to do something and ordering them not to tell you. But if they do, then that is a whole other issue.

Comment: And if you're the employee, and the task is at all significantly impacting your other work: "Sure, we can do that. Let me talk to my manager about when we can slot it in. "

Comment: @keshlam I would suggest *not* starting the response with "sure, we can do that" as many people won't hear the next sentence - all they'll hear is the agreement to do the task.

Comment: Good Advice... Also if you don't directly report to this executive then get your direct superior involved as well. Chain of command exists for a reason and by subverting that this executive is probably negatively affecting your direct superior's goals as well.

Comment: @keshlam: You should ask them what other task you should drop be drooped.